# How Comparator Interface in Java 8 become a @FunctionalInterface

Tags: java, java-8

I would like to clarify my understanding of `@FunctionalInterface` a bit.
As far as I know, we can add @FunctionalInterface annotation on an interface that only has **one abstract method** (It can have multiple default and static methods though.

In Java 8, `Comparator<T>` interface has been marked with @FunctionalInterface so it can be used in Lambda Expression but when I opened the definition, I could see 2 abstract class there

`int compare(T o1, T o2);` and `boolean equals(Object obj);`

I would like to understand how it is possible to have more than 2 abstract methods in the functional interface and still not getting any error? Help me to clear my understandings on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is answered in the [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) of the `@FunctionalInterface` annotation:

> If an interface declares an abstract method overriding one of the
>   public methods of java.lang.Object, that also does not count toward
>   the interface's abstract method count since any implementation of the
>   interface will have an implementation from java.lang.Object or
>   elsewhere.

So presence of the presence of `boolean equals(Object obj);` in the Comparator interface does not add to the count of abstract methods present in the interface and so we can apply `@FunctionalInterface` to this interface.

Answer (score 3):

`boolean equals(Object obj)` is already defined on `java.lang.Object` so it is not really a "new" method in the interface. It is only "repeated" here because the implementation contract -- which is part of the Javadoc but not enforced by the compiler -- is being made stricter (it has to be consistent with `compare`).